# Replace blanks with 0

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data

Hi I want to replace blanks in my dataframe as 0. When I run this:

```
list(df['col'])
```

I get list of values['12345','78910',...., '' ,'5678', '12344', '', '7654'].
How can I replace these '' missing values with 0. I want the whole df to be replaced by 0 when there is a blank like this ''.

Comment: you either need `replace` or `fillna` however it's hard to say as we don't know if you have blank whitespaces i.e `['1', '2', '', '','9']` or `[1,2,3,NaN,5]` anyway please see [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

As you have strings, I imagine that the best is to convert [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with 0 the invalid/missing values:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

For the whole DataFrame:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Example output:

```
     col
0  12345
1  78910
2      0
3   5678
4  12344
5      0
6   7654
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['12345','78910','' ,'5678', '12344', '', '7654']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>>
data = {'a': ['12345', '78910', '', '5678', '12344', '', '7654'],
        'b': ['295', '7', '', '8', '', '37484', '901']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

    a       b
0   12345   295
1   78910   7
2       
3   5678    8
4   12344   
5           37484
6   7654    901

>>>
out = df.replace('', 0)
print(out)

    a       b
0   12345   295
1   78910   7
2   0       0
3   5678    8
4   12344   0
5   0       37484
6   7654    901
```